# Vue code throws error, has no default Export on Editor Terminal

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

There is no problem in Browser, i am getting needed output. But why is this showing in Editor Terminal constantly?

Any Help would be much appreciated.

**No Default export Error:**

```
Module '"/vue3/src/components/TestIcon.vue"' has no default export.
```

My component looks like this.

**TestIcon.vue**

```
<template>
  <span v-html="svg" class="icon-wrapper" ref="iconWrapper"></span>
</template>    
<script setup lang="ts">
import type { tycon } from "test-icons";
import { computed, onMounted, ref } from "vue";
import { completeDataSet } from "test-icons";

const props = defineProps<{
  icon: tycon;
  class: string;
  color: string;
  height: string;
  width: string;
}>();
const iconPassed = completeDataSet.find((item) => item.name === props.icon);

const svg = computed(() => iconPassed?.data);

const iconWrapper = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null);

onMounted(() => {
  iconWrapper.value?.lastElementChild?.firstElementChild?.setAttribute(
    "class",
    props.class
  );

  iconWrapper.value?.firstElementChild?.setAttribute(
    "style",
    "width:" + props.width + "px;height:" + props.height + "px;"
  );

  iconWrapper.value?.firstElementChild?.firstElementChild?.setAttribute(
    "fill",
    props.color
  );
});
</script>
```

**App.vue:**

```
<template>
  <main>
    <TestIcon :icon="'icon_test'" :class="'tests'" :height="40" :width="40" />
  </main>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import TestIcon from "@/components/TestIcon.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    TestIcon,
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Also tried this code too. But didn't work either. 

color: {
  type: String,
  required: false,
  default: () => "",
};

Comment: Is this the kind of error that exists since .vue files are not typescript and there is no .d.ts definition for Vue components in general or your individual .vue files specifically? I believe vue-tsc has a dts emit behaviour which will ensure vue files get declaration files next to them that correspond to e.g. their props, computeds and so on. Then perhaps typescript will be able to see that the .vue file DOES have a default export. In general editors need Volar or Vetur to be able to edit Vue files, and I believe Volar is the most stable for Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **vue-cli**, then checkout if `shims-vue.d.ts` file existed with content:

```
/* eslint-disable */
declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
  export default component
}
```

Or if you're using **vite**, checkout `env.d.ts` file and the content would be:

```
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

/* eslint-disable */
declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
  export default component
}
```